# Как организовать чтобы всегда был запущен процесс обработки очередей в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Сейчас запускаю команду для запуска php artisan queue:work.
Как сделать чтобы очереди всегда были запущены?
Хостинг не поддерживает возможность  запустить sudo apt-get install supervisor

Comment: Supervisor https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: У меня нет прав на хостинге запустить sudo apt-get install supervisor

Comment: Вариант тупой, но попробуйте черещз крон. Это не не будет работать реалтайм, но хотя бы раз в минуту, если очереди не срочные. 
Если срочные - то меняйте хостинг, так как скрипт проверки очереди должен рабоать постоянно, а для этого должен кто то этим управлять - а значит нужно дополнительное ПО (супервизор или иное).

Comment: Через крон если запускать - надо писать свой костыль, который будет каждую задачу отдельно запускать. Иначе хостер заблокирует аккаунт, т.к. тот будет порождать фоновые процессы очередей